# Upsert without an external Id

Tags: apex, platform-event, upsert, externalid

We have external system that is pushing an event  using Platform events saying that an asset is changed. I have created a Platform event object and a trigger on it, make a webservice callout to get the changed asset information and need to perform an upsert (We have a unique key on Asset object). However, I realized that platform event objects do not support external ids.

How do I perform an upsert without an external id? I can query the asset object and if the list size is greater than zero, update the asset record and if the list size is 0, I can insert a new asset.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The Platform Event itself doesn't need to have the data marked as an External Id.

If you have an External Id field on `Asset`, and receive data in your platform event that matches 0 or 1 value for that External Id field on `Asset`, then you can upsert.

ex.

```java
Asset toBeUpserted = new Asset(
    My_External_Id_Field__c = myPlatformEvent.Regular_Text_Field__c
);

upsert tobeUpserted My_External_Id_Field__c;
```